# After upgrading to Xcode 9.0, existing application getting an error "dyld: dyld_sim not compatible mach-o"

Tags: ios, xcode9

After upgrading to `Xcode 9.0`, existing application getting an error:

> "dyld: dyld_sim not compatible mach-o"

Any comments?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried ⇧⌥⌘K?

Comment: Sorry i did't get this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the `build setting` you need to replace `architectures` to Standard like as screen shot ... works for me. [image]

Answer (score 0):

Delete the 32bit architecture and use default architecture in build settings

Comment: I tried to delete it on my Xcode 9.0 ,but it does't work. Please mention how to dot it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This occurred because ios 11 compatible for 64 bites,
to solve this issue 
**follow this steps:**

1-app target>>Building Settings >>valid Architectures must be in this order armv7 armv7s arm64
2-target>>Building Settings >>Build Architecture Only >> Debug-->YES and release--> NO.
3-.plist :make sure that :Required device Capabilities contain armv7 .
4-if you used third party libraries make sure that this libs compatible with 64 bits.